# How to do this lagrange multiplier question? (max / min)

Tags: maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I have the following question

> Using the method of the Lagrange multipliers, find the maximum and minimum values of the function $$f(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z^2$$
> where $(x,y,z)$ is on the sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$$
> Using the result obtained to show that for arbitrary non-negative numbers $a,b$ and $c$,
> $$(abc)^\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

My thoughts are to use the equation $L = f + \lambda g$, where $f$ is the same as above and $g$ is just $x^2+y^2+z^2 - r^2 = 0$

But when I compute this, for example, I get :

$L_{x} = 2xy^2z^2 + 2 \lambda x = 0$ which means that the $x$ cancel ? I think I've made a silly mistake, and was hoping someone could explain how to do this properly.

And if you can, could you guide me on the second part of the question

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Maybe this can help. $x$ cancels only in this one (if assumed to be non-zero), but you have at least two more $L_{y}$ and $L_{z}$. The proper answer would be solution of system of 3 equation (or more exactly four. You should include $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=r^{2}$).

Comment: @kolobokish I see we have 2 other eqs. $L_{y}, L_{z}$ but when I do this it forms the same problem as $L_{x}$. And if I try combine them together I don't know where to go from there -- do you have any further ways to go about this?

Comment: If we decide that non of the variable is 0. Then we can conclude the following (from each equation). $y^{2}z^{2}=-\lambda$; $x^{2}z^{2}=-\lambda$; $x^{2}y^{2}=-\lambda$. From which by equality of right sides you have equality of left sides. From any 2 you'll have $x^{2}=y^{2}=z^{2}$. Putting into sphere equation you'll got $3x^{2}=r^{2}$. Or $x^{2}=\frac{r^{2}}{3}$. This can be shown to be maximal (not minimal).

Comment: @kolobokish wow, okay I didn't see it from that angle, thank you for the help

Comment: You are welcome. But I don't see yet how to come to the conclusion about $a,b,c$ geom. mean vs arith. mean.

Comment: @kolobokish I am having the same problem I'm just revising and my prof doesn't provide solutions so I thought I would ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z^2$ and given constraint $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2 = 0$

Applying Lagrange Multiplier method,

$x^2y^2z^2 = \lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2)$

$2xy^2z^2 = 2 \lambda x$

$2x^2yz^2 = 2 \lambda y$

$2x^2y^2z = 2 \lambda z$

So if you take the first equation for example, you have $\lambda = y^2z^2, $ if $x \ne 0$

Plugging in the second and third, you get $x^2 = y^2 = z^2$ and given the constraint

$x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = \frac{r^2}{3}$

Similarly check other critical points.

EDIT:
Specifically on the argument sought in the question for non-negative numbers,

Say, $a = x^2, b = y^2, c = z^2$. So they are non-negative and as per given constraint, we have

$a+b+c = r^2$

Maximum value of $\displaystyle abc = \frac{r^6}{27}$ or we say $\displaystyle abc \leq \frac{r^6}{27}$

So, $\displaystyle (abc)^{1/3} \leq \frac{r^2}{3} = \frac{a+b+c}{3}$

Comment: Thank you! Always helping :)

Comment: Do you have a method to go along with this, sorry if it may be long -- if it is, could you just provide a few hints ?

Comment: No it is not long. It is pretty much what I put in my comment. I will edit. Btw for the minimum, you need to see that $x^2y^2z^2 \geq 0$ given they are square. So if we take the other value $x = 0$ (or any one of them as zero). $y^2+z^2 = r^2$ and we get minimum of $x^2y^2z^2 = 0$.

Comment: I see, for the minimum thank you -- and appreciate the help always

Comment: I just added. pls check.

Comment: I worked on this for a bit longer, and I just checked and I got the same thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome!